# SPI Flash Error

Tags: fpga, spi

I am using spartan 3 fpga board , and as i am doing on linux i am using astriaekipro to flash the designs.
Till now it was working fine , but now it is showing that SPI flash ID do not match.
I have gone through the source code of the astriaekipro and commented the function for ID check and flashed it again.
Even after the complete flashing process, old design is not getting erased and new design not getting flased, i am only able to see output of the old design.
I am  assuming the SPI Flash in FPGA is corrupted.
Any Suggestions Please

Comment: Why don't you use impact from Xilinx?

Comment: I would second @JonathanDrolet question.  You should use the manufacturer's tools as much as you possibly can.  Situations like this can commonly be avoided by doing this.  I highly doubt the SPI Flash on the FPGA is corrupted unless it is very old has been extremely abused.  Those things are pretty sturdy now days.  Not saying it is impossible, just unlikely.